# Can NAS from NetApp and EMC Celerra manage tiered storage?

Tags: netapp, storage, celerra

My question is short, and I probably do not now enough about this to be able to ask a really good question, so let me know if you need any additional information to help me out.

Here goes;
does NAS boxes from NetApp and EMC (Celerra) manage HSM/Tiered storage themselves, or will one need extra products to manage HSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetApp doesn't really have tiered storage (as far as I know).  You just basically put one size disk in the thing and go.

Celerra can if you have the newest OS on it that supports FAST.